# Book recommendation for a novice

Tags: security, privacy

I'm 30+ with a family and working in a non-IT field. I've been getting into IT privacy and security and playing around with Ubuntu. What would you recommend for me to read so I can learn more. I'm kind of looking for a book which will give a good foundation of knowledge, doesn't get too technical too quickly, and captures some of the excitment of learning new things. Too much to ask?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a shopping type question.

Comment: We tend to do this our self by playing around with the desktop and server and using google to find cool things to do :) No books required. I agree with Zeis though do have a look at https://itsfoss.com/best-ubuntu-books/

Comment: If you want to study linux get started with the Comptia Linux+ guide ebook. It is great for novices.

Answer (score 1):

maybe "The Ubuntu Book" which comes with a free copy of ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
or, "The linux Command Line"